# How to pass context through static factory method without this Lint error?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a static class for `GoogleSignIn` so I can reuse it in multiple fragments. Since the `GoogleSignIn` methods require a context I pass it through the constructor.
However it throws this `lint` error. Should I be concerned about passing context through this constructor?

[image]

```
public class AuthStateManager {

    private static final String TAG = "AuthStateManager";

    private static AuthStateManager authStateManager;
    private static GoogleSignInClient  googleSignInClient;
    private static GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount;
    private static GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;

    private AuthStateManager() {
    }

    public static AuthStateManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if(authStateManager == null){
            authStateManager = new AuthStateManager();
            googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions
                    .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.idclient))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, googleSignInOptions);
            googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
        }

        return authStateManager;

    }


    public String getIdToken() {
        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            return googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isUserSignedIn() {
        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Other than `TAG`, why are the rest of those fields `static`? They would not appear to need to be `static`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up removing the static from those variables and ended up putting them in the private constructor. https://i.imgur.com/jHgsAEM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of Singleton class is to have a Class as singleton.

Since you has only one instance of `AuthStateManager` and all your variables are `private`, you could remove `static` from variables

**UPDATE**

```
public class AuthStateManager {

    private static final String TAG = "AuthStateManager";

    private static AuthStateManager authStateManager;
    private GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
    private GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount;
    private GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;

    private AuthStateManager() {
        googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions
                .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.idclient))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, googleSignInOptions);
        googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
    }

    public static AuthStateManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if(authStateManager == null){
            authStateManager = new AuthStateManager();
        }

        return authStateManager;
    }


    public String getIdToken() {
        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            return googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isUserSignedIn() {
        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If I made it non static I wouldn't be able to access it inside fragments https://i.imgur.com/z4em9Ob.png

Comment: And if I made the AuthStateManager factory method static, I would then have to make the variables of that class static, which would then cause the ```lint``` error.
https://i.imgur.com/OZqbNG9.png

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE, my mistake, only `AuthStateManager`  of this should be still static

Comment: I didn't think of putting the ```GoogleSignIn``` methods inside the private constructor. I also added the context inside the private constructor as well. Here's the final code that doesn't throw any errors: https://i.imgur.com/jHgsAEM.png Thanks for your help. I was struggling on this for a while.